# Minified React error #423 and #418 (Math.random)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to A/B test some ads on my React / GatsbyJS website. For that I render the ads depending if a random number is bigger or smaller than .5

I'm receiving a `Minified React error #423` and `Minified React error #418` error, because I'm using `const randomNr = Math.random()`, which React doesn't like because the output will be different on render than on hydration.

I can't find a simple workaround to fix this issues. I tried using `useEffect`, `useState` or `useLayoutEffect`, but that breaks the script of the ads. Since my method works and doesn't break anything, I could simply ignore it, but I want to remove the error for SEO reasons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this via generating the number only on the client side. Don't use server side to do this. You'll also lose benefits of build generation data that Gatsby provides.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const randomNr = Math.random()

    // your logic
  }, []); // this will trigger ONCE only after the first render of the page
```

If you have dependency, like you need a new random number everytime a value changes, then

```
useEffect(() => {
        const randomNr = Math.random()
    
        // your logic
      }, [yourValue]); // this will trigger EVERYTIME when yourValue changes
```

yourValue is usually a state.

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't work, since it will create a random number only after the page, and therefore also the ads, rendered.

Comment: So you might need to save your ads in a state, then put your state value in useEffect for "yourValue". Then, whenever your ads changes (rendered), that useEffect will trigger and it'll generate a new random number.